# Rails - adding a class to filepicker_image_tag with filepicker-rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filepicker.io

Using:

```
gem 'filepicker-rails'
```

I can't seem to add a class like this:

```
<%= filepicker_image_tag @user.photo_url, w: 32, h: 32, fit: 'clip', class: 'my_class' %>
```

This seems like it should be easy.

Am I doing this incorrectly, or is it not possible?

Comment: try ``html: { class: 'myclass' }``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.

I just had to curly-bracket the filepicker options, and then assign the class like this:

```
<%= filepicker_image_tag @user.photo_url, { w: 32, h: 32, fit: 'clip'}, class: 'my_class' %>
```

Comment: update: adding a bootstrap class of `img-thumbnail` will make it behave as the bootstrap class should make it behave, but if you inspect the element, you won't explicitly see the `img-thumbnail` class.

Comment: I have not had that same issue with `img-responsive` but I am using an old version of the gem: filepicker-rails (1.0.0). The class appears in the image tag as expected.